# how to load complex object in POST request using Spring MVC

Tags: xml, forms, spring, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I am learning Spring and Spring MVC primarily from Spring documentation and other forums and sometimes asking questions in stackoverflow if i am not finding an explanation.

I understood how to load an object when a user submits a form.
I learnt using Model Attributes.

But i did not find samples which explains or briefly covers how to proceed when trying to load complex object.

For my better understanding of the concept, i came up with a problem for which i am trying to find a solution using Spring MVC

A page when user clicks on submit will sends information to server in a XML format.
I have tried to give a highlevel structure of the xml.

```
<xml>
<fileOne>
  <filename>posttoserver</filename>
  <totalpages>2</totalpages>
  <pageList>
    <page>
      <number>1</number>
      <url>/doc/part/1.jpg</url>
      <metadata>
          <information>some information about the page</information>
      </metadata>
    </page>
    <page>
      <number>2</number>
      <url>/doc/part/2.jpg</url>
      <metadata>
          <information>some information about the page</information>
      </metadata>
    </page>
    <page>
      <number>3</number>
      <url>/doc/part/3.jpg</url>
      <metadata>
          <information>some information about the page</information>
      </metadata>
    </page>
  </pageList>
</fileOne>
</xml>
```

I am trying to achieve loading this back to objects where the parent object file should have element fileName, TotalPages and List of Pages object.

I need some direction on how to proceed with this.

Thank you for reading.
Appreciate your time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Java schema for this document you only have to add this object as a parameter into your endpoint. All unmarshaling will be done by Spring by using Jaxb converters.

So you will have:

```
public void yourEndpoint(@RequestBody YourObject yourObject) {
 ...
}
```

If you haven't got you xml object in Java, you can create simple POJO annotated by @XmlRootElement containing your structure:

```
@XmlRootElement
public YourObject implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```